# Receiving 'error multiple values for index' in a simple DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several lists that I'm trying to enter into a data frame:

```
    mydates = [0, 6, 15, 21, 30, 37, 45, 53]
    prices = [30.4, 32.5, 31.7, 31.2, 32.7, 34.1, 35.8, 37.8]
    mylist = [6.907894736842111, -2.461538461538464, -1.5772870662460567,4.807692307692319,
    4.2813455657492305, 4.985337243401747, 5.5865921787709505, -3.9682539682539684]
```

I enter

```
    df = DataFrame(prices, mylist, index=mydates, columns=['Prices', 'Percentage
    s'])
```

And receive this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'index'
```

While if I enter this everything works fine.

```
    df = DataFrame(prices, index=mydates, columns=['Prices'])
```

Could someone please tell me how to fix what's wrong? .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [604]: d = {'dates' : mydates, 'prices': prices, 'mylist': mylist}

In [605]: df= DataFrame(d)

In [606]: print df
   dates    mylist  prices
0      0  6.907895    30.4
1      6 -2.461538    32.5
2     15 -1.577287    31.7
3     21  4.807692    31.2
4     30  4.281346    32.7
5     37  4.985337    34.1
6     45  5.586592    35.8
7     53 -3.968254    37.8
```

EDIT:

As  Wouter Overmeire pointed out, you can use `DataFrame({'prices': prices, 'mylist': mylist}, index=columnanme)` to index by column.

Comment: Thanks! How would I remove the index on the left?

Comment: or set it from the beginning: df = DataFrame({'prices': prices, 'mylist': mylist}, index=dates)

Comment: @root but how do you rearange the columns? If suppose I want the columns to be in this order: ['prices', 'dates', 'mylist']